# AVPlayer Video play button crossed out

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am currently trying to retrieve an .mp4 from a URL.

The video is accessible from a web-browser but the play button is crossed out. Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Code in question

```
 NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.videoURL];

// create an AVPlayer
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:movieURL];

// create a player view controller
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.player = player;
[player play];

// show the view controller
[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
controller.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Screenshot of device

[image: iOS Video playback failure]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way apart from UIWebView to play youtube video inside iOS application. Also you can redirect to youtube application by passing your video url.So youtube application will handle rest of the things

You can read the guidelines of YouTube section 2 point 10 [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=en)

You can use youtube player [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#installation)

```
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> 

NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0597" ofType:@"mov"]];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:movieURL];
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];
AVPlayerViewController  *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: item];
playerViewController.player = player;
[playerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.width)];
playerViewController.delegate=self;
playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my videos did not play was because in the xml, where I was retrieving the url for the videos, I did not start the url with `http://`.

The code for this player works as it should.